# Proper way to install mitmproxy's certificates?

Tags: certificates

I run a a few servers, 2 of which have mitmproxy correctly installed. I follow the same process as the other 2 servers on an identical 3rd server, but mitmproxy does not work. I get a TLS error every time. Here's what i do:

```
sudo apt install mitmproxy
mitmproxy
cd .mitmproxy
mv mitmproxy-ca.pem mitmproxy.crt
sudo cp mitmproxy.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
```

this process usually works, but is now bugging out. Any way to fix?

edit: the error is Client Handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for [website]

Comment: I do use a slash before copying, that was a mistake on my end lol. The TLS error is: Client Handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for [website name]

Comment: Please do not use comments to add info that belongs in the question. Use the edit feature and add the info to the body of the question.